# How to display and style elements depending on their value (Angular 4+)?

Tags: css, angular

I would like to create a conditional template that will display a different content depending on the referenced-value of a {{status}}.

I have a table and the status column, I need the text color to change depending if it's "Active" or "Deactivated".

It doesn't seem to work, how can I make it work with Angular 4+?

HTML:

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="status">
      <th class="users__header-row" mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>STATUS</th>
      <td class="status" *matCellDef="let user"> {{status}} </td>
</ng-container>
```

CSS:

```
.status[matCellDef="ACTIVE"] {
        color : green
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ngStyle` like this

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="status">
  <th class="users__header-row" mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>STATUS</th>
  <td class="status" *matCellDef="let user" [ngStyle]="{'color':status === 'Active' ? 'green' : 'red' }" > {{status}} </td>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: How does this work with the format I have currently?

Answer (score 1):

just use ngClass

like

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="status">
      <th class="users__header-row" mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>STATUS</th>
      <td class="status" *matCellDef="let user"> <span  [ngClass]="{'green' : condition}">{{status}}</span> </td>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: It seems that ngClass is not working with matCellDef

Comment: is there any error, did you try defining .green{color :green}